# How to suppress sql query output and show only the number of rows

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I have the following powershell command which displays the number of rows in a sql table. This works but it also includes the header:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "01-SQL1\INSTANCE22" -Database master -Query "select Count(*) from dbo.mytable"
```

The Output I get is:

```
Column1
-------    
2450 <= This line is actually displayed under Column1 on a separate line. I just couldn't get it to display properly here.
```

The only output I need is to show me the row count if it's greater than X number of rows, otherwise print "Less than 5000 rows found." How do I do this?

Comment: Either pipe to `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Column1` -or- enclose your command in parentheses and append `(Invoke-Sqlcmd ...).Column1`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mix numbers with text, so your best bet is to return that value into a variable and then set a rule to display whatever you want: however, you can also accomplish this with pure SQL:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(*) < 5000 THEN
               'Less than 5,000'
           ELSE
               CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(10))
       END
FROM [dbo].[myTable] ;
```

Comment: How would you put that together with the command I included so that it's a one liner...perhaps with @" and "@ ?

Comment: You can just strip out the white space - I only added it so it's easier to see what's going on:  SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 5000 THEN 'Less than 5,000'ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(10)) END FROM [dbo].[myTable] ;

Comment: FYI, the SQL ANSII standard is to not require white space other than spaces: any SQL code can be reduced to a single line, as long as you don't have two dashes for a comment in there (--). And if you do need a comment, use the /*...*/ multi-line comment format, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select count(*) as totalcount from table

Comment: Thanks but I already have Count(*) so I'm not sure what you mean. I also need it to display it only when it's greater than X number of rows.

Comment: select case when Count(*)>x then Count(*) Else NULL End you show try this

Answer (score 0):

this should answer your question. 
sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -Q "if ((select Count(*) from spt_values) < 5000) PRINT 'Less than 5000 rows found'"

ps version: just thew query that's different

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database master -Query "if ((select Count(*) from spt_values) < 5000) PRINT 'Less than 5000 rows found'" -verbose

Comment: I need to stick to powershell commands so Invoke-SqlCmd is what I have to use.